# Cannot connect to another server database (Authentication with old password...)

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I try to connect to another server and database for transfer data purposes.
But unfortunately the image below appear. May I know the reason and can show me how we can create connection to that server?

My current server using latest version (MySQL 8) and other database that I want to connect using MySQL 5(something like that). Please advice Thank you.

**IMAGE :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-8.0 doesn't support the "old password" mechanism from MySQL-4.X. Update the database driver and it will hopefully connect correctly.

Comment: Do you mean update mysql8 or the other server database?

Comment: Update the MySQL connector that provides the MySql.Data.MySqlClient... in the backtrace image. This updated version should talk to MySQL using modern authentication mechanims. Hopefully it is compatible with your existing application.